# Outlook AddIn, there are two duplicate Ribbon shows in Ribbon bar .

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I developed Outlook AddIn and create the setup project for 64bits  using Visual Studio 2013.

My office is 64bit as well. Currently my problem is that there are two ribbons menu instead of one.

After installating, I open my outlook and check. I can only see one ribbon menu.

but I load my outlook second time, there can be see two ribbons. so I mouse over to these two ribbons.

one is my setup project name and another one is my outlook addin name. but they do the same purpose

and all layouts and functions are same. I would like to know why did two ribbon come out instead of one.

Best Rgds,

dartfrog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't unregister the add-in from Visual Studio before running the installer. Use the Clean context menu button as shown on the screenshot:

[image]

You can disable add-ins in the host application. Just go to the COM Add-ins dialog and unselect the required one.